# Eager load EF Core collection type members

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

Assume I have two classes:

```
class Foo
{
    List<Bar> someList
}

class Bar
{
    string a;
}
```

I want to eager load a `Foo` instance from EF Core and include `Foo.someList.a`

When I try to straight up write an include such as

```
.Include("Foo.someList.a")
```

I get an exception:

> An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.InvalidIncludePathError':
>
> Unable to find navigation 'Foo.someList.a' specified in string based include path 'a'.
>
> This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.InvalidIncludePathError' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in
>
> 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'."}    System.InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this reference page from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager).

What would work in your case is to *include multiple levels*, like this:

```
var result = context.Foos
    .Include(foo => foo.someList)
    .ThenInclude(bar => bar.a);
```

Edit:
OP has manifested preference for the overload of `Include` that takes a `string` instead.

```
var result = context.Foos
    .Include("someList.a");
```

Comment: but what if I use strings?

Comment: Added to the answer. The problem is that you must start the branch from the root property (in this case, `somelist`), instead of the entity name itself.

Comment: but then how do I get the entity itself?

Comment: I am assuming you are querying on a store of `Foo` entities. Can you show your full code when you query? I mean, in which object are you calling `.Include("Foo.someList.a")`?

Comment: `context.Foos.Include("someList.a")` will return every `Foo` with its respective `someList` and `someList.a` so I'm not sure what the issue is. "How did I get the entity itself?"

Comment: Note that in OP example the type of `a` is `string`, so none of these apply. Consider asking for clarification before answering unclear and poorly defined questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code as shown here:

```
 var data = _context.Foos.Include(b => b.someList).ThenInclude(b => b.a);
```